# properly set up navigation controller as a root for a uitab bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am a little bit confused and cannot make things to work.

So, this is my code in my app Delegate.

```
 // If the device is an iPad, we make it taller.
    _tabBarController = [[AKTabBarController alloc] initWithTabBarHeight:(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 70 : 50];

 NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    CurrentViewController * tab1VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab1"];

    // dummy controllers
    CurrentViewController * tab2VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab1"];
    CurrentViewController * tab3VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab1"];
    CurrentViewController * tab4VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab1"];


    [_tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           tab1VC,
                                           tab2VC,
                                           tab3VC,
                                           tab4VC,
                                           nil]];

    [_window setRootViewController:_tabBarController];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then, in my storyboard I have the image below :

[image: StoryBoard Image]

So, I have my ViewController and I clicked **Embed In > Navigation Controller**

I want to have a different navigation controller for each tab.

Inside my CurrentViewController I have this when button is clicked :

```
- (IBAction)dummyButton:(id)sender {
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UserSettingsSetupViewController *userSettingsSetupController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserSettingsSetup"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:userSettingsSetupController animated:YES];
}
```

And apparently nothing is pushed into the navigation Controller because nothing opens.

Doing some research, I saw that this is because **[self navigationController]** or **self.navigationController returns nil.**

but why is that? Should I add any code? I thought that by doing that from storyboard, it shouldn't be nil? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments. First of all, if you're using a storyboard, don't create view controllers in the app delegate; drag all the controllers you need into the storyboard. There's no need for any added code in the app delegate at all.

Your problem is caused by trying to mix storyboard controllers and code in the app delegate. You are instantiating tab1VC and making that the controller in the first tab -- that controller doesn't "know" anything about the navigation controller you added in the storyboard. If you wanted to do it in code (which I don't recommend), you would need to instantiate that navigation controller instead (it will take care of instantiating its root view controller), and add that as the first item in the viewControllers array.

My advice is do it all in the storyboard. Change the class of the tab bar controller there to AKTabBarController, and set its tab bar height in its init method or viewDidLoad.